# iPhone : In-App purchase query

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, in-app-purchase

I want to add In-App purchase functionallity in my app.

My app contains many feature. In the free version, Some features of my app will be accessible and some features are disabled.

What i want to do is, i want to enable all the feature once the user pays for full version of my app.

How do I store flags in iOS keychain ?

How can I do this ?

Is there any examples or good links ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways you could achieve this:

- Using your own server and delivering the content once the app is purchased succesfully.
- Using the iOS keychain to store some flags.

I will talk about the second point here. I will assume you can't get your own server.

The easiest way to do is to code in "disabled" features into your app, as you normally would. But store a flag a somewhere, say, a flag called "contentHasBeenPurchased". You could store this flag anywhere; in a plist, in NSUserDefaults, but these are insecure ways to store your flag because a jailbroken app could easily access your application's sandbox. These methods are secure with non-jailbroken users, for the most part... There is software that allows you to access the iOS filesystem and edit plists from there. So yeah, storing this specific flag in a plist or NSUserDefaults is certainly not a good idea.

So you are left in storing this flag "contentHasBeenPurchased" in the iOS keychain, because it is encrypted. If you don't know how to use the iOS keychain, it's a bit complex to learn, but it will certainly pay off in the near future. After you have your flag in the keychain, it's just matter of checking whether its value is true or false to enable the purchased content. When the user purchases the app, just set the flag to true, and you are ready to go.

Comment: @ Sergio : But I am confused with if the once the user buys the full version of app and then user closes the app. How do i know that its purchased or not ? Basically, I am targetting for non-consumable.

Comment: Well, if you are not willing to do any flag checks, then you will never really know whether the user purchased the app or not. So everything you need to do is to change a flag once the user purchases the app, and check it when the app opens up again the next time. Hope I am answering your new question correctly.

Comment: @Sergio: Good idea ! And How about iOS keychain option you gave. Does it also work similarly (sets flag and check for it) ? And any good link if you can share.

Comment: Actually, my idea involves using the iOS keychain ;) Lol. You have to store your flag there with a true or false value. The iOS keychain will allow you to store your flag in an encrypted manner so users can't tamper with it. This is is a good tutorial for the iOS keychain: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/3/29/simple-iphone-keychain-access.html . So basically, all you need to do is to make your flag in the keychain itself, retrieve it when you are doing some checking, and changing it's value when the user purchases the app.

Comment: @Sergio : I have read the information but still I am not getting that how iOS keychain stores my flags ??

Comment: Think of NSUserDefaults, but with an encryption. Here, let me provide you a nice class an ex Apple worker made: http://gorgando.com/blog/tag/sfhfkeychainutils That class will highly simplify the iOS Keychain working process. Except you will need to work with NSString flags instead of BOOL ones like you may have planned. Like you can see this class only has three methods; getPasswordForUsername and setPasswordForUsername should do the trick to set and check your flag.